# How to implement mixed selection model for QTableView

Tags: qt

I have custom table view that shows content of custom abstract model.
I need to implement mixed selection for these view.

When user clicks on the first column the whole row should be selected (AbstractItemView::SelectRow). 
When user clicks on cell in other column just the particular cell should be selected (AbstractItemView::SelectItems).

What need to do to achieve such behaviour?

Comment: No, QAbstractItemView::SelectItems doesn't block selectRow, I set this behaviour but my example still works(if I set selectColumns then it is not work) So you do something wrong or you setSelectionMode for example to QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection. If so, change it to QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    //if(!index.column()) more elegant
    if(index.column() == 0)
        ui->tableView->selectRow(index.row());
}
```

Catch `clicked()` signal and check is it first column. If so, then `selectRow()` with current row (`index.row()`)

I use here `QTableView` but `QAbstractItemView` has `clicked` signal [too](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clicked).

Comment: thanks, this is an valid solution. Except, I've used pressed() signal instead of clicked() for better visual behaviour.